# Nginx: Difference between unix:/ and unix:///

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

What ist the exactly difference between:

```
uwsgi_pass unix:/foo/bar.sock
```

and

```
uwsgi_pass unix:///foo/bar.sock
```

in a nginx cfg for a uwsgi pass ?

What is the better choice for a django production environment ?

Comment: I won't provide an answer, because I'm not 100% certain, but IIRC, the `//` is basically part of the `unix://` declaration, and the third `/` is the beginning of your file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between:

```
uwsgi_pass unix:/foo/bar.sock
```

and

```
uwsgi_pass unix:///foo/bar.sock
```

is the same as between:

```
uwsgi_pass unix:/foo/bar.sock
```

and

```
uwsgi_pass unix:////////////////foo////bar.sock
```

or, the same as between:

```
root /data/www/site.ru;
```

and

```
root ///data/www/site.ru;
```

I'm sure, now you've got the poing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule) recommened `uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/example.com.sock;` syntax.